# Display all currently defined variables

Tags: php, variables

Is this possible without a debugger?

I mean, we have $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, etc. I'm looking for something like $_CURRENT_VARS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`$GLOBALS`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) contains all global variables. Or you use [`get_defined_vars()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php).

Answer (score 0):

well, it's overkill, but you can call `phpinfo()` to display (essentially) everything.